# Laravel: Carregar imagens e arquivos linkados

Tags: laravel, url

Eu tenho o seguinte código: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/v1.css">`, mas a pagina não carrega ele. Ao inspecionar elemento aparece o seguinte erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como mostra a imagem, ela vem com o link:  http://localhost/naslojas/css/v1.css, porém se eu adicionar o *public* na url:  http://localhost/naslojas/public/css/v1.css, funciona normal.

Isso está acontecendo com mais de um arquivo e com imagens também. Já me falaram que eu precisaria configurar os *hosts* do *xampp* e do *windows*, mas não tenho a menor ideia de como fazer isso e se esta é realmente a solução.

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obs: mude os caminhos de acordo com a sua instalação.

Vai no seu arquivo `hosts` em:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

E adiciona nova linha:

```
127.0.0.1 naslojas.dev
```

depois, vai no seu arquivo `httpd-vhosts.conf` em:

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
```

E adiciona:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName naslojas.dev
    ServerAlias www.naslojas.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\naslojas\public"
    ErrorLog "logs/dominio1-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dominio1-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\naslojas\public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

após tudo configurado, reinicie o apache.